# Is it possible to use DistributedDataParallel with PyTorch Estimator

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

We know that Horovod is suppported. Is there an example script which uses DistributedDataParallel and Pytorch estimator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify nccl or gloo as distributed data parallel backend, in addition to MPI with Horovod. See the *distributed_training* parameter of [PyTorch Estimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-core/azureml.train.dnn.pytorch?view=azure-ml-py).